# Difference between perl 5.8 and 5.10

Tags: perl, perl5.10, perl5.8

I'm compiling some information related to the differences between 5.8 and 5.10. Can someone please point out the major differences, or tell me where I can begin my research?

Comment: 5.8.0?  5.8.5?  5.8.8?  also helpful to know the *purpose* of your compilation.

Answer (score 6):

[`perldoc perl5100delta`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perl5100delta)

> NAME
>
> perl5100delta - what is new for perl 5.10.0
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> This document describes the differences between the 5.8.8 release and
>          the 5.10.0 release.
>   ...

Important changes introduced in Perl v5.10.1 can then be found in [`perl5101delta`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perl5101delta)

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good starting point: http://dev.perl.org/perl5/news/2007/perl-5.10.0.html